# Created compiz startup file. Can't find it anymore and it needs to be deleted

Tags: compiz, startup

I tried to make compiz start up automatically. It starts up automatically now, but it causes the main ubuntu menu to be disabled. I would like to change the way it starts up, but I forgot which file I created/edited to make compiz start automatically. How can I see which file makes the compiz process to start up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you've made the changes using Terminal, check the history log. To do that, simply type `history` in a terminal window.

Comment: I wanted to do that, but apparently the log got cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a user-specific configuration change? Try looking in `~/.config/autostart`.

If it is system-wide, try `/usr/share/gnome/autostart` or `/usr/share/autostart`

Comment: Thanks, but I have looked in those directories. Haven't been able to find anything. It starts up only when I start the ubuntu session. If I start a ubuntu 2D session it doesn't start compiz.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pstree` or `gnome-system-monitor`, you might be able to find the parent process. That parent process might give you a clue since it might load configuration files you wrote and execute them.